# Sending Inner class as a param from Queueable apex to a batch

Tags: apex, batch, queueable-apex, inner-class

I have a queueable apex that calls to a batch.

Inside the queueable class - I have inner Class that writes a log with incorrect fields.

The Inner Class inside the **queueable class** :

```
public class ErrorClassToSend{
        Date todayDate;
        String name;
        String email;

        List<String> contactErrorFeidls;
        List<String> grantErrorFeidls;
        List<String> coursesErrorFeidls;

        public ErrorClassToSend(){
            this.contactErrorFeidls = new List<String>();
            this.grantErrorFeidls = new List<String>();
            this.coursesErrorFeidls = new List<String>();
            this.todayDate = Date.today();

        }

    }
```

Then I'm creating a Map when the email is the key.

```
 Map<String,ErrorClassToSend> errorMapCls = new Map<String,ErrorClassToSend>();
```

After filling the Map I calling the Batch with another param - Map of contacts named contactMap :

```
StudentFileBatch bStud = new StudentFileBatch(contactMap,errorMapCls);

Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(bStud, 200);
```

**In my Batch :**

I created the same inner class also in the batch (ErrorClassToSend), and I created a variables to store the income params from the queueable class :

```
Map<String,String> contactMap = new Map<String,String> ();
Map<String,ErrorClassToSend> errorMap = new Map<String,ErrorClassToSend>();
```

and then inside the Batch constructor :

```
public StudentFileBatch(Map<String,String> contactMap ,Map<String,ErrorClassToSend> errorMap) {
    this.errorMap.putAll(errorMap);
  }
```

I'm getting the Error when compliled :

```
Constructor not defined: [StudentFileBatch].<Constructor>(Map<String,String>, Map<String,StudentFileQuable.ErrorClassToSend>)
```

I tried to send Map to the batch and getting it with the same way, but same error.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One class is not the same as another, even if it has the same name. However, you can modify your batch to simply use the first's:

```
Map<String,StudentFileQuable.ErrorClassToSend> errorMap = new Map<String,StudentFileQuable.ErrorClassToSend>();
```

Alternatively, you could pull out the class into its own top-level class, since it's to be shared between the two.

The constructor would be likewise modified in your batch class:

```
public StudentFileBatch(Map<String,String> contactMap ,Map<String,StudentFileQueble.ErrorClassToSend> errorMap) {
    this.errorMap.putAll(errorMap);
}
```

You could also avoid a bit of overhead by assigning the map directly:

```
public StudentFileBatch(Map<String,String> contactMap ,Map<String,StudentFileQueble.ErrorClassToSend> errorMap) {
    this.errorMap = errorMap;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, these classes don't have the same name since their (fully qualified) name includes the outer class (and namespace where that is applicable). Only the local name looks the same.

Comment: Thanks. I actually thought it gonna work when I defined the same inner class inside both of the classes. Thank you